# LabelCell to NumberCell

Tags: java, excel, jxl

Is it possible to convert jxl LabelCell to  jxl NumberCell somehow?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `labelCell`, you can try the following snippet to create a `NumberCell`:

```
NumberCell numberCell = new Number(labelCell.getColumn(), 
                                   labelCell.getRow(), 
                                   Double.parseDouble(labelCell.getContents()));
```

Comment: I still get java.lang.ClassCastException: jxl.read.biff.LabelSSTRecord cannot be cast to jxl.NumberCell

Comment: Did you use my code? I'm not doing any casting. I'm creating a new NumberCell using properties from the LabelCell.